# How do I chown to inherit parent directory's owner and group or the current account user

Tags: linux, git, terminal, chown

In terminal I know I can

```
chown whatever:whatever .*
```

What I want to do is dynamically set username and group to the current domain owner rather than root. Is there an easy way to do this?

Some background: I'm pushing to my server using Git as root then checking out to public_html.  This makes any new files and directories owned by root:root. I want to add a line to hooks/post-receive to change the owner to the domain user rather than root but I don't want to have to specify the domain user explicitly if I don't have to.

Comment: So the "domain user" is the owner of the parent directory? In that case you could set the SUID and SGID bits on the directy. Git doesn't know about user ids, btw., so you don't need to push as root.

Comment: Be careful with ".*".  You might wind up changing things you don't intend to...

Comment: The domain user is the /home/user (I'm pushing to a whm server)

Comment: By default every directory inside that directory is owned by them. When I push with git I'm ssh'd in as root. This is I assume why my checked out files are owned by root:root

Answer (score 8):

The simples think I could think of is

```
chown -R `stat . -c %u:%g` *
```

You might also use `$(...)` instead of backticks here.

Comment: Nice! I do wonder is there a way to get the domain/account user from the terminal (sorry I don't know how to refer to this user but I mean the /home/user)

Comment: Also I wonder if I can run the git checkout command as this user from within post-receive to stop the owner:group being wrong in the first place?

Comment: @user844621, you're doing it wrong, read [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/git-users/UC_D5b3f0oE/KAdmTmxvPF4J).

Comment: @user844621, to answer the first comment, look at the `id` command as well as `$UID` and `$GID` environment variables.

Comment: thanks. 'id' gives me the current user I'm ssh'd in as.  Let's say I've ssh'd in as root but then navigated to /home/anotheruser/public_html
Is there another variable that will give me 'anotheruser'?

Comment: That other page hurt my head a bit :) but I think I can put
    sudo www-data /bin/sh
or
    sudo anotheruser /bin/sh
instead of
    !#/bin/sh
at the top of my post-receive
might solve the problem

Comment: @user844621, uh, but if you navigated to a user's home directory you already know what user is that, no?

Comment: I was just using this as an example, the post-receive file that this command would go in doesn't know that

Comment: @user844621, could you may be ask another question explaining your requirements in detail? (And if you will do so, please link it here for the reference.)

Comment: Done - new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479792/how-do-i-set-owner-and-group-on-git-files-on-checkout-from-hooks-post-receive

Answer (score 2):

Probably not exactly what you want to do, but this is the first thread that comes up in a search about setting files/folders to a parents owner. I accomplished this by the 'reference' switch. So be in the child directory and then run:

```
chown * -Rv --reference=/PATH/TO/PARENT
```

this sets all the contents of the child directory to any reference file you care to, in my case, i am using the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

This will recursively set all files and directories to the owner/group of the current directory.

```
 #!/bin/ksh
 OWNER=`ls -ld ./ | cut --delimiter=" " --fields="3"`
 GROUP=`ls -ld ./ | cut --delimiter=" " --fields="4"`
 chown -R $OWNER:$GROUP *
```

Test the command out to make sure it works with your flavor of Linux.

```
 #!/bin/ksh
 OWNER=`ls -ld ./ | cut --delimiter=" " --fields="3"`
 GROUP=`ls -ld ./ | cut --delimiter=" " --fields="4"`
 echo $OWNER:$GROUP
```

Comment: This looks spot on, thanks! Will test when I'm next on my computer.

Comment: Instead of dancing with so many text processing, it's better to use good old `stat`.

Comment: `stat` does seem like the better and more accurate way to approach this.